# sharepoint 2007 list items concurrent edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a list with 100 columns. When users do concurrent edits in items, it was a huge waste of effort since the the most recent user update will be saved and other users get the general error message.

The impact would be huge if the column count is high.

How do we make the notification to the new user who is trying to edit the existed edit item ?

Is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "the general error message"? If a list item is edited concurrently by several users, you cannot save your changes. You will see an information (not error) message telling you to go back in the browser, copy your changes, refresh the page, reapply the changes and save.

Comment: teylyn, yes, I mean to say the same information would be displyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try OOB Checkin/Checkout feature. If the item is checked out user will get to know that the item is being edited by other user.

Answer (score 0):

how can "check in / check out" be enabled for lists? I thought this is only possible for Document Libraries? (I`m using SP2010)

Comment: you are right Checkin/Checkout is only available in libraries. My mistake.

Comment: DarkTomate, yes. the check in/check out feature would be enabled only for document libraries, not for lists.